# priority_queue top return by reference

Tags: c++, inheritance, priority-queue

I have the following priority_queue with items of type base.
The problem is, when I get item from the Queue with top(),
then call its f() function via base reference object, it does call the 
f  of base class but not the overriden f. 
I want child object's f() to be called.
Any help? Thanks..

```
    #include <queue>
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    class base {

        public:
            int id;

            virtual void f() const {

                cout << "base f()" << endl;
            }

    };

    class D1: public base {

        public:

            void f() const {

                cout << "D1 f()" << endl;
            }

    };

    class D2: public base {

        public:

            void f() const {

                cout << "D2 f()" << endl;
            }

    };

    bool operator<(const base& b1, const base& b2)
            {
        return b1.id > b2.id;
    }

    int main()
    {

        priority_queue<base, deque<base>, less<deque<base>::value_type> > Q;

        D1 d1;
        D2 d2;

        Q.push(d1);
        Q.push(d2);

// this is not something  I want
        const base& b = Q.top();
        b.f();        // base f()


// this works as I want
    const base& b2 = d2;
    b2.f();        // D1 f()

    return 0;

    }
```

Comment: [Object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing). If you want polymorphic behavior, you need to store pointers in your container.

Comment: I tried that before, it worked but I got strange runtime error, thus I want to avoid it. Is that the only way?

Comment: Well then, go back to almost-working program and concentrate on fixing the strange runtime error.

Comment: I won't. Any other idea?

Comment: The C++ standard library doesn't support the idea of polymorphic union. `std::variant` is non-polymorphic. So unless you want to take on some real expert's coding better go for pointers. Try to just store `shared_ptr` instances. That way you minimize problems with object lifetimes.

Comment: You just rejected the canonical solution, without any good reason. Unless you explain _why_, the question is a dupe.

Comment: Fine with me. You are welcome to keep plugging at the non-working program.

Comment: Ok, I can fix the solution with pointers but this is not the actual issue. I really wonder if there is other workaround?

Comment: Suppose I have to push copy of the object but not pointer to it because the object is local and will disappear. Actually I will have event priority queue and will feed events into it from different ISR s and consume from a dispatcher task.

Comment: Allocate a copy on the heap (at a spot where you still know the real type of the object), and push a (possibly smart) pointer to that. You cannot store objects by value in a container and expect polymorphic behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same polymorphic premise as using pointers, but here's a possible alternative using [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper):

```
#include <functional>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class base {
    public:
        int id;

        virtual void f() const {
            cout << "base f()" << endl;
        }
};

class D1: public base {
    public:
        void f() const {
            cout << "D1 f()" << endl;
        }
};

class D2: public base {
    public:
        void f() const {
            cout << "D2 f()" << endl;
        }
};

bool operator<(const base& b1, const base& b2)
{
    return b1.id > b2.id;
}

int main()
{

    priority_queue<std::reference_wrapper<base>, deque<std::reference_wrapper<base>>, less<deque<std::reference_wrapper<base>>::value_type> > Q;

    D1 d1;
    D2 d2;

    Q.push(d1);
    Q.push(d2);

    // this now works as you want?
    const auto& b = Q.top();
    b.get().f();    // D1 f()


    // this works as I want
    const auto& b2 = d2;
    b2.f();        // D2 f()

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: With g++ 5.4, I got "‘reference_wrapper’ is not a member of ‘std’" error.

Comment: Unfortunately you'll need C++ 11 or higher to use this or smart pointers. "Bare" pointers is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you Phil. At least C++11 has a solution for this.

Comment: Note that this has the same lifetime issues as storing a pointer - a reference to a local object will become dangling exactly the same way a pointer would, when the object goes out of scope. You'd still need to create a copy of the object someplace that would outlive the local scope - that is, on the heap.

Comment: @Igor, got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `shared_ptr` as they are polymorphic by nature. Below code achieves what you want using `shared_ptr`

```
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class base {

    public:
        int id;

        virtual void f() const {

            cout << "base f()" << endl;
        }

};

class D1: public base {

    public:

        void f() const {

            cout << "D1 f()" << endl;
        }

};

class D2: public base {

    public:

        void f() const {

            cout << "D2 f()" << endl;
        }

};

bool operator<(const base& b1, const base& b2)
{
    return b1.id > b2.id;
}

int main()
{

    priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<base>, deque<std::shared_ptr<base>>, less<deque<std::shared_ptr<base>>::value_type>> Q;

    D1 d1;
    D2 d2;

    Q.push(std::make_shared<D1>(d1));
    Q.push(std::make_shared<D2>(d2));

    // Works!
    const shared_ptr<base> b = Q.top();
    b->f();        // D1 f()

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Sorry I forget to mention that I am on embedded platform and only have c++03, thus cant use shared_ptr. thanks though.

Comment: Unclear whether shared ownership is desired here. If in doubt, don't share!